# Update from jQuery 1.7.1 to jQuery 1.10.2

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I had such js code it was running with `jQuery 1.7.1`

```
$("(.editor-field .input-field):has(input[data-val-required])").each(function () {
        $(this).prev().find("label").append("<strong style='color:#ff0000'>*</strong>")
        })
```

But now i changed to `jQuery 1.10.2` and having problems with it. Getting an error message:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: (.editor-field .input-field):has(input[data-val-required]) jquery-1.10.2.js:1850
```

Is there any chance to fix that?

Comment: include jquery-migrate.js link: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first set of parentheses are not necessary. Just remove them.

This should do what you want:

```
$(".editor-field .input-field:has(input[data-val-required])")
```

That is assuming you want the `has` part to only apply to the `.input-field`.